# Is there a word for the parallel world of dictators?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the "parallel world" of dictators?

Most dictators were surrounded by people who don't dare to tell the truth.

The result: the dictators didn't see the world like it is, but only how they wanted it to see. They didn't know how the average people felt.

Is there a word for this "parallel world" of dictators?

Comment: The dictators are *dogmatic* or *opinionated*.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that they lived in an **echo chamber**: they only heard what they had already said.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

How about **bubble** -- one word -- or **alternate reality** -- two words? Both describe the "parallel universe" of dictators.

Many people live inside **bubbles**. In doing so, they insulate themselves from information from outside the **bubble**, and at the same time, they ensure that all the information they receive is from inside the **bubble**. From Dictionary.com:

> **bubble**: anything that lacks firmness, substance, or permanence; *an illusion or delusion* (emphasis added)

**Alternate reality** is a synonym for parallel universe. [Wikipedia] It's fair to say that dictators live in **alternate realities**. To paraphrase the OP:

> They don't see the world as it is, but only how they want to see it.
>   They don't know how average people feel.